# Move Uploaded Multiple Files

Tags: php

So the main problem is that I can't seem to move the images to my designated folder. I have this database that records the name and directory. It seems to work well. It's only the images that fail to move to the folder.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group" align="left">
<label for="aialbum">Album:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="aialbum" name="aialbum">
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cms_albums";
    $showalbums = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while($getalbum = mysqli_fetch_array($showalbums))
    {
    $album = $getalbum['album_name'];
    echo "<option value='$album'>$album</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<br><label for="aipicture">Image/s:</label>
<div class="form-group">
<input type='file' name='aipicture[]' id='aipicture[]' multiple>
</div>
</div>
<div align="right">
<input class="btn btn-default" type='submit' name='aisubmit' value='Submit'>
</div>
```

Here's my PHP code: (Update)

```
if(isset($_POST['aisubmit']))
{
    $aialbum = $_POST['aialbum'];
    $aipicture = $_POST['aipicture'];
    $filecount = count($aipicture);

    for($i=0; $i<$filecount; $i++)
    {
        $temp_name = $_FILES[$aipicture[$i]]['tmp_name'];
        $org_name = $_FILES[$aipicture[$i]]['name'];
        $path = "../img";
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $path);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cms_album_photos (album_name, picture) VALUES ('$aialbum', 'img/$aipicture[$i]')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.href="home.php";';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<noscript>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=home.php" />';
    echo '</noscript>'; exit;
        }
```

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? Is there any error message given?

Comment: Why is your html code not in a form?

Comment: There where no error messages.

Comment: Use form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `if(isset($_POST['aisubmit']))` at your php code , so it knows when you trigger the button

Comment: There's also this on the php

$aialbum = $_POST['aialbum'];
$aipicture = $_POST['aipicture'];
$filecount = count($aipicture);

I also tried this, but it didn't work.

foreach ($_FILES["aipicture"]["name"] as $i => $pImage) {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["aipicture"]["tmp_name"][$i], "../img");
    }

Comment: J. Ende, I have already put those codes. I just didn't include them. Sorry.

Comment: Can you share full code please

Comment: `$_FILES['$aipicture[$i]']` should be `$_FILES[$aipicture[$i]]` [look here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$target_Path = "asd/".basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_Path );
```

Comment: Same thing happened. :(

Answer (score 0):

improve your code from this

```
$temp_name = $_FILES[$aipicture[$i]]['tmp_name'];
$org_name = $_FILES[$aipicture[$i]]['name'];
```

To this

```
$temp_name = $_FILES[$aipicture]['tmp_name'][$i];
$org_name = $_FILES[$aipicture]['name'][$i];
```

Hope this help!